# Key Error when re.sub replace the string with dictionary

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, dictionary, replace

First, I want to apologize for my terrible English - I'm not Englishman.

I have the problem with this line of my code:

```
expression = re.sub("\w+", lambda m: "{}".format(functionsDICT[m.group(0)]), expression)
```

The dictionary raise me an error:

```
KeyError: 'pi'
```

The dictionary (functionsDICT) contains the names of functions from my class. There's no 'pi', because it comes from other module. So I want to replace, by dictionary, "expression" string and don't stop the code when re.sub find something is not in dictionary (It remains in the string unchanged). Something like try...except.

Thank you in advance for your help. I hope, You understood me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`dict.get(key, default)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method:

```
expression = re.sub("\w+", lambda m:
    '{}'.format(functionsDICT.get(m.group(0), m.group(0))), expression)
```

That is, if the first argument `m.group(0)` is not found in the dictionary, `get` returns the second argument `m.group(0)` instead - in your example substituting `"pi"` with `"pi"`.

Notice that you can use `str()` instead of `'{}'.format()` unless your values do something fancy with default format specifiers.